# What does this Powershell command mean in English?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

In Exchange Management Shell, you can write a query to display administrator activities.

`Search-AdminAuditLog -Startdate ((get-date).AddDays(-5)) -EndDate (get-date) | where{$_.caller -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (MSExchangeHMWorker)"} |select Caller, Rundate, ObjectModified, CmdLetName, @{n="Parameters"; e={$e=$null;$_.CmdLetParameters|%{$e += ( " -" + $_.name.tostring() + " '" + $_.value + "'")};$e}} | ft -autosize`

Most of the commands make sense but can anyone explain the @... part in English? Specifically this part:

`@{n="Parameters"; e={$e=$null; $_.CmdLetParameters | %{$e += ( " -" + $_.name.tostring() + " '" + $_.value + "'")};$e}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called a "Calculated property".  It's a way to add a property in your selected object with the name specified by `n=` and having the value resulting from expression `e=`.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx

Comment: Just to add to this correct answer, the @{} syntax builds a hash table containing the name and expression of the calculated property.  Check the link provided for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explains what "n=" is however "e=" part still looks very cryptic; I know that this expands $_.CmdLetParameters to key-value pairs. Can you explain that part?